# R formula syntax understanding - how the args works

Tags: r, formula

There is some formula that is used to pass some function as argument formula.
All I want is to understand how this formula works and what is x_i or y_i, or what are ways to create my own formulas using this syntax, for example, simple circle formula x^2 + y^2 = 16;

I wasn't able to find some useful documentation or example that lets me understand how the syntax works here... I don't know the language R, but I'm familiar with many other languages, so it'd be great if someone can explain how this works...

```
my_formula <- list(
  x = quote(runif(1, -1, 1) * x_i^2 - sin(y_i^2)),
  y = quote(runif(1, -1, 1) * y_i^3 - cos(x_i^2))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to point out is that your object `my_formula` isn't a formula. It's a list of two calls:

```r
class(my_formula)
#> [1] "list"
class(my_formula$x)
#> [1] "call"
```

The "call" objects are just that - unevaluated calls to some R functions. The symbols `x_i` and `y_i` are just symbols that haven't been evaluated yet. Of course, if you try to evaluate these calls, you get:

```r
eval(my_formula$x)
#> Error in eval(my_formula$x) : object 'x_i' not found
```

Because the variables don't exist in the calling environment. If we want to, we can specify an environment or list in which the variables *do* exist:

```r
eval(my_formula$x, list(x_i = 1, y_i = 1))
#> [1] -0.2587035
```

We could use this inside `lapply` to evaluate both calls with the same data:

```r
lapply(my_formula, eval, env = list(x_i = 1:10, y_i = 1:10))
$x
 [1] -0.1807416  3.3997202  5.5344464 10.8595742 16.6505876 24.7780384 33.3294949 41.3666577 54.1489721
[10] 66.5793089

$y
 [1]   -1.118590   -3.972655  -14.702628  -36.052731  -73.277122 -124.782105 -198.653156 -296.474984
 [9] -422.348169 -579.149676
```